# Pass Vue form submit event values to Axios without v-model

Tags: forms, vue.js, axios, form-submit

I have a form that gets submitted, but I'm catching the submit event and passing it to a Vue method. My question is, how can I pass that event to an Axios call. I'm not wanting to create a bunch of v-models, or create a bunch of variables based on the event.

```html
<template>
    <form @submite.prevent="handleFormSubmit">
        <input type="text" name="someforminput">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        handleFormSubmit(submitEvent) {
            axios
                .post('/the/post/route', submitEvent)
                .then(response => {
                    // Handle response
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // Catch errors
                })
                .finally(() => {
                    // And finally
                });
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

I found where I could reassign the values by grabbing them from the event `const someFormInput = submitEvent.target.someforminput.value`, but I'd rather just pass along the info without having to redeclare it. It seems like this should be possible.

Basically, if Frank makes a pizza and heads out to deliver it to Jim but Victor (Vue) intercepts the pizza, I want Victor to just pass the pizza along to Alex (Axios) for delivery, not pull apart all the ingredients, remake the pizza, and place it in a new box before passing it along.

Comment: You will have to bind the input(s) and values to something, otherwise the value will never be captured.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are specifying the form submit handler inside a vue sfc's template tags, you'll **have** to use the vue component to at least receive the event. Whether you handle the axios request in the method or just forward it along to some function in a js file is up to you.

If you want to use a vue method as little as possible, you could do something like this.

```
<template>
    <form @submite.prevent="handleFormSubmit">
        <input type="text" name="someforminput">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>

<script>
import { importedHandler } from './formHandlers.js';

export default {
    methods: {
        handleFormSubmit: e => importedHandler(e.target.someInput.value);
    },
}
</script>
```